# Find all elements with a class, save their IDs into an array then pass that array of IDs into a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

I'm working with waypoint and animated CSS to animate elements on a page. I want to find all elements with a class of `animated`, store their IDs in an array called `ids` and then pass that array through a callback I wrote called `animatedContent`. HTML structure example:

```
<div id="element-1" class="animated">
  <h2>Content</h2>
</div>
<div id="element-2" class="animated">
  <h2>Content-2</h2>
</div>
<div id="element-3" class="animated">
  <h2>Content-3</h2>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
var ids = $('.animated').map(function(index) {
  // this callback function will be called once for each matching element
  return this.id;
});

var animatedContent = function(animateItem) {
  // hide our element on page load
  $(animateItem).css('opacity', 0);
  // takes element and passes it through the animatedContent Callback
  $(animateItem).waypoint(function() {
    $(animateItem).addClass('fadeInRight');
  }, { offset: '100%' });
};
animatedContent("#"+"ids");
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass `$('.animated')` to the function?. `animatedContent($('.animated'))` and then inside the function `animateItem.css('opacity', 0);`, etc

Comment: ... or `$('.animated').each( function() { ... } );` -- Don't bother collecting the ids, that just means you have to select the DOM element twice; once to get the id then again selecting by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Your question doesn't actually say what is wrong, but …)

Your script is mostly good, except for the very last line. `animatedContent("#"+"ids");` is the same as `animatedContent("#ids");` - not using the variable `ids` at all, just a string containing the word "ids".

Your animatedContent takes an argument which will need to be suitable for `$(...)`, i.e. it should be a CSS selector like `#a,#b,#c`. I suggest when creating the `ids` array you prepend the `#` immediately:

```
var ids = $('.animated').map(function(index) {
  return '#' + this.id;
}).get();
```

Then you can simply join this array at the end:

```
animatedContent(ids.join(','));
```

*Edit:* As pointed out by Rory in his answer, your approach is a bit redundant. Ideally, you could apply your `animatedContent` function directly to an array of elements. This way, the function itself is somewhat generic and reusable (i.e. it could be used with other elements or selectors) while being quite short:

```
function animatedContent() {
  let item = $(this);
  // hide our element on page load
  item.css('opacity', 0);
  // takes element and passes it through the animatedContent Callback
  item.waypoint(function() {
    item.addClass('fadeInRight');
  }, { offset: '100%' });
}
$('.animated').each(animatedContent);
```

Comment: Hey Aurel, so I like the direction you took with making this code block generic, however, I'm getting an $(...).forEach is not a function error

Comment: @stolercloud Whoops, my bad. jQuery has `.each()`, not `.forEach()`.

Comment: You are the man!!!! Thanks for helping me with this. I'm right at the beginning of understanding programming blocks and how they work together so thank you so much for helping me sreamline my function. This is working 100% now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is almost correct, you just need to pass the selectors as a string in to the function, after prefixing them with a `#`, like this:

```
var ids = $('.animated').map(function(index) {
  return '#' + this.id;
});
animatedContent(ids.join(','));
```

***However*** the point of making an array to hold the `id` attributes from a jQuery object which you then pass to another function, to then turn back in to a jQuery object is completely redundant. You can just work with the selected elements directly in the function, like this:

```
var animatedContent = function() {
  $('.animated').css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fadeInRight');
  }, { 
    offset: '100%' 
  });
}
```

Comment: oh man, so I just updated my code with your response and now I'm getting an error that ids.join is not a function.

Comment: first would not have a `#`

Comment: An added bonus is that the `.animated` elements don't even need to have an `id` any more.